# How to improve productivity of JavaFX GUI during resizing?

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX application with main stage in FXML. The problem is: during resizing window by button or by draging the margin of the window it takes application a second or two to restructure and resize components of the main stage. So some black fields or strange location of the components appear, and during draging some vibration of components is observed and that's why it's impossible to set the necessary size. Of course, they very soon dissappear, but maybe it's possible to avoid them?